# What is the correct syntax to use MySQL functions inside a PHP string

Tags: pdo

Im building a string for a query ib mysql PDO like this:

```
$fields  = "landlord.*, CONCAT('&pound;', FORMAT(landlord.RatePayable, 2,'en_GB'))";
```

Then later executing like:

```
$stmt = $cnx->prepare( "SELECT ".$fields. " FROM tblPaid " ); etc ...
```

However when i output to the browser im getting the mysql function echoed out instead of the result of the concatenation and formatting. How do i escape the mySQL functions in order to get desired effect.

Comment: You need to show us some more code. Nothing in what you posted would create any output to a browser.

Comment: I sussed it ... its because i use PDO getColumnMeta() to loop through and output the column names of the table. The column content is formatted correctly its the column name which is output exactly as stated in the SELECT part of the query string.